# How (Time Column + Time Column) in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem with time calculation.

For example: I have a table1 called `TabA` with fields: `id`, `A1` (data type Datetime), `A2`( Data Type Datetime):

```
TabA
--------- ---------- ---------- 
id         A1           A2
 001      8:10:00      9:20:00
```

I want to calculate `(A1+A2)`. The result in the example I expect is: 17:30:00 or 17h 20mn 00sn

Please help to show this at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` is not the same as `Time`.
The `DateTime` data type supports the `+` operator for adding:

```
DECLARE @A datetime, @B datetime

SELECT @A = '08:10:00',
       @B = '09:20:00'

SELECT CAST((@A + @B) As time)
```

Result: `17:30:00`

The `Time` data type, however, dosen't support the add operator, so writing this:

```
DECLARE @A time, @B time

SELECT @A = '08:10:00',
       @B = '09:20:00'

SELECT CAST((@A + @B) As time)
```

Will result with an error:

> Operand data type time is invalid for add operator.

Comment: Note that the `TIME` datatype cannot contain time larger than 24 hours. I'd prefer to keep the result in a DATETIME for that reason.

Comment: @TT You are correct, of course, I thought it's too obvious to mention, but then again, I might be wrong :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for immediate answer. That's quite correct and the result I wanted.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)